# prosgres sql of using limit and fetch

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, coldfusion

There are many solutions to the above questions from which i checked and tried but mine is always giving an error

I had some code converted from postgres to sql server  but facing some issues

```
select * FROM errors OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

the above in sql server
converted from posgres as:

`select * from errors offset #start# limit #total#;` works

but not in sql server, what should i do there

Comment: What part of this is ColdFusion?

Comment: There appear to be a couple of ColdFusion variables in the second query.

Comment: yes, they are, i tried converting the postgresql to sql server, but where not able to make it work properly

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, OFFSET...FETCH is part of the [ORDER BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql) clause. Ordering is needed with `OFFSET` because result set order is undefined without ORDER BY; the same query could return different results even though the underlying data is the same.

Below is example syntax, guessing an an appropriate column name.

```
SELECT *
FROM Errors
ORDER BY ErrorTimeStamp
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: got it, but there is an issue if i try to use it like this

Comment: select count(*) AS total FROM errors ORDER BY id desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY

Comment: i do not where to add group by and group by does not need the ordering, so not sure if the group by will work when the sorting is done

Comment: The query in your comment returns only a count and one row. No ORDER BY...OFFSET is needed in that case. Grouping and sorting is independent but the ORDER BY columns(s) need to be in the select list so one would usually order by the group by columns. For example: `SELECT ErrorType, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM Errors GROUP BY ErrorType ORDER BY ErrorType OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;`

Comment: you are mentioning, i can use the count within the one query itself, no need for a second query or if there is a need, i do not need the fetch

Comment: This query returns one row: `select count(*) AS total FROM errors`. Offset and fetch is only needed for pagination of multi-row queries.